# How to enable linking floating point library in TurboC?

Tags: c, floating-point, turbo-c

I'm newbie in C language... Just want to ask how to enable linking floating point library in TurboC?

Comment: Why are there so many TurboC/TurboC++ questions the last few weeks?  That compiler (and target platform) are old and non-standard.  There are several good, free, modern C/C++ toolchains (and IDEs for them) available. Today you shouldn't have to worry about floating point libraries unless you're doing embedded work.  If you're specifically interested in "computer archeology", that's one thing, but if you're looking for tools to help you learn C or C++, please move to something else (for you own benefit and sanity, if no other reason).

Comment: @Michael Burr actually, I'm willing to move on but I've got to follow first the requirement of our school. I know it's unfortunate but I can't help but do this...

Comment: @aerohn: I'm sorry that it's forced on you; I understand that sometimes it's out of your control (we've all been in similar situations).  I wonder - do schools still teach Geography using maps from when the USSR was still around?

Comment: @Michael Burr: definitely! They engaged the reason that we've got to be fluent enough in old languages before we move onto another level of language. They said, the language that will come up will be easy for me to comprehend after this. I'm wondering why!?

Comment: @aerohn: if they really said that using Turbo C will teach you better fundamentals than learning C using a better compiler, then they're just wrong, so there probably isn't really a "why" beyond, "this is how I've been doing it before". Sorry. It's not about the language itself, the problem is the particular implementation of it which is pre-standard, DOS-specific and hasn't been maintained for 20 years.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: OK... I understand :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [comp.os.msdos.programmer FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/msdos-programmer-faq/part2/section-5.html):

> "Floating point formats not linked" is
>   a Borland run-time error (Borland C or
>   C++, Turbo C or C++). Borland's
>   compilers try to be smart and not link
>   in the floating- point (f-p) library
>   unless you need it. Alas, they all get
>   the decision wrong. One common case is
>   where you don't call any f-p
>   functions, but you have `%f` or other
>   f-p formats in `scanf()` or `printf()`
>   calls. The cure is to call an f-p
>   function, or at least force one to be
>   present in the link.
>
> To do that, define this function
>   somewhere in a source file but don't
>   call it:
>
> ```
> static void forcefloat(float *p)   
> {
>      float f = *p;
>      forcefloat(&f);    
> }
> ```
>
> It doesn't have to be in the module
>   with the main program, as long as it's
>   in a module that will be included in
>   the link.