# Reading struct values using pointer

Tags: c

I have a struct that contains a float var. I am trying to read the value using a pointer to a struct. Here's the code:

```
struct mas {
    float m;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct mas *ms;
    ms=(struct mas*)malloc(sizeof(struct mas));
    scanf("%f",&(ms->m));
    printf("%f",ms->m);
    return 0;
}
```

But running the program produces the following error:

```
scanf floating point formats not linked
```

The compiler used is Borland Turbo C++ (3.0) on a Windows PC. Why is this so?

Comment: It's neither necessary nor recommended to cast the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: I think you would be better off getting a more modern compiler (TC++3 is 20 years old) like Visual Studio Express.

Comment: Please see the answer to this StackOverflow question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223453/how-to-enable-linking-floating-point-library-in-turboc

Comment: not doing so produces a complier warning "NonPortable pointer conversion"

Comment: @DavidGrayson: That is what the "close as duplicate" feature is for.

Comment: Cody, I respectfully disagree.  Malloc returns a void*, and should always be cast to the receiving type to avoid a warning.

Comment: @Fletch: What's the rationale? I'm aware that `malloc` returns `void*`, but that is not inherently an argument for casting it. The whole point of inventing `void*` is that it doesn't *require* a cast, unlike in the old days when `malloc` returned `char` or `int` or something (not sure exactly, that was before my time). No compiler that I know of warns for this.

Comment: @Cody not really, using a C compiler yes, no need to cast but when you use a C++ compiler you need to cast -- although in C++ one should use new/delete instead.

Comment: @Anders: Yes, agreed, no one is talking about C++ here. The question has been tagged `[c]` from the beginning.

Comment: @CodyGray: agreed, now that I'm reading up, I realize you're absolutely right - sorry.  I guess it's been a long time since I've used a straight c compiler.  Even on straightup function based C projects with no OO, I end up using a C/C++ compiler (and I'll even use // for comments because I love them)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be helpful: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/msdos-programmer-faq/part2/section-5.html

From the article:

> Borland's compilers try to be smart and not
>    link in the floating- point (f-p) library unless you need it. Alas, they
>    all get the decision wrong. ... (To force them to link it) define this function somewhere in a source file but don't
>    call it:

```
static void forcefloat(float *p)
{
  float f = *p;
  forcefloat(&f);
}
```

Also:

> If you have Borland C++ 3.0, the README file documents a slightly less
>    ugly work-around. Insert these statements in your program:

```
 extern unsigned _floatconvert;
 #pragma extref _floatconvert
```

Comment: in the old MS-DOS days that made a difference with the 640KB mem limit, but nowadays...

Answer (score 3):

> Why is this so..

Because there's [a bug](http://c-faq.com/fp/fpnotlinked.html) in your ancient, useless compiler. Upgrade to a newer one that properly handles floating point operations.

The latest version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is a good choice, or you can download Microsoft's [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express) package for free, which bundles their compiler with a world-class IDE.

Comment: Well explained, great suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to compile and run this code under GCC 4.2.1:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct mas{
    float m;
};

int main()
{
    struct mas *ms;
    ms=malloc(sizeof(struct mas));
    scanf("%f",&(ms->m));
    printf("%f\n",ms->m);
    return 0;
}
```

Are you missing any `#include` statements? I don't think you need to cast the result from `malloc()`.