# Error while reading a float value in a structure in C

Tags: c

Following is the code to read an array of structures with two string and one float data member and display the same. While giving input to the program, just after entering the second string I am getting the error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct student
{
    char name[20];
    char usn[20];
    float marks;
};

void main()
{
    struct student s[3];
    int i;
    clrscr();

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the details of student %d\n", i+1 );

        printf("Enter the name of the student\n");
        scanf("%s", s[i].name);

        printf("Enter the usn of the student\n");
        scanf("%s", s[i].usn);

        printf("Enter the marks of the student\n");
        scanf("%f", &s[i].marks);
    }

        printf("The student details are\n");
        printf("Name\tusn\t\t\tmarks\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t%s\t\t%f\n", s[i].name,s[i].usn,s[i].marks );
    }

    getch();
}
```

As soon as i enter the second string i.e., usn I got the following error

> scanf : floating point formats not linked
>
> Abnormal program termination

What's the problem here?

Comment: i changed `void main()` to `int main(void)`, added a `return 0;`, removed the conio.h parts and it works for me: https://ideone.com/cJOfoi

Comment: Looks like a problem with building the code. Probably you work on some embedded architecture and your program is not linked with a floating point library.

Comment: It seems you are using Turbo C ? Is It ? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6223626/2425366

Comment: Yeah - floating-point support is often optional, and by default off, in many embedded environments.

Comment: Is there an overriding reason for 'marks' to be floating-point?  Can a, (maybe scaled up), int/longint value be used instead?

Comment: Do not use Turbo C anymore. It's not a "real" C compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a problem with your compiler.Some compilers for small machines leave out certain floating point support if it looks like it will not be needed.

[Check out this link](http://c-faq.com/fp/fpnotlinked.html)

Comment: Got it 'mch'. Thanks everybody