# Array of float, inside array of structures

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct students
{
  int reg;
  float m[5];
}s[6];
void main()
{
   int i,j;
   for(i=0;i<6;i++)
      {  
         printf("For student %d: ",i+1);
         printf("\nEnter Registration No.:");
         scanf("%d",&s[i].reg);
         for(j=0;j<5;j++)
         {
           printf("\nEnter marks in subject %d: ",j+1);
           scanf("%f",&s[i].m[j]);  //Error arises here 
         }
      }
```

I need to scan for marks in subject 1-5 for a student
so, I made array of marks for 5 subjects.

```
float m[5];
```

I have to do this for 6 students
so, I made array of structures students.

```
struct students{
}s[6];
```

The Error message:

> floating point format not linked
>
> Abnormal program termination

Comment: sounds like Borland to me. You have to add a library for floating points there (forgot how). see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223453/how-to-enable-linking-floating-point-library-in-turboc

Comment: What is your compiler? What is your environment?

Comment: The compiler is GCC

Comment: It's borland turbo C++ 3.0

Comment: Please make up your mind. If you're using Turbo C++ then you're *not* using GCC.

Comment: Let's know what's it? @Someprogrammerdude